# Ошибка AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text' Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Сравниваю что в "find_text_for_assert_comment" есть текст "Test Comment"

```py
find_text_for_assert_comment=browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]")
    assert "Test Comment" in find_text_for_assert_comment.text,f"Комментарий не добавлен"
```

Но получаю ошибку в консоли

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Так же пробовал XPATH написанный руками, результат тот же

```
//div[contains(text(),'Test Comment')]
```

Так выглядит в браузере

```
<div class="e-comment-item__content">
            Test Comment        </div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите свою проблему конкретней. Например что вы собсвенно пытались сделать. И пожалуйста не выставляйте свой код в картинках, перекопируйте его в свой вопрос.